# Binary image straightening in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I have a set of binary images, which look like this:

[image]

I want to eliminate the noise and straighten the lines out. The final goal is to convert the contour into a polygon that is as smooth as possible. I can eliminate most of the noise by using dilation and erosion, getting to something like this:

[image]

It looks better but the contours don't really form straight lines. Do you know of a better approach I could use? Could I use Hough transform here to extract lines from these shapes?

Comment: is that from a point cloud (laser scans, structure-from-motion)?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

May sound weird, but as your image is fairly noisy, with parasitic features, it can be beneficial to blur and shrink it in size before any processing. This will remove the irrelevant small scale details.

[image]